# How can I configure more than one REST API servers in ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have to create multiple REST API servers using ml-gradle.

I know I can configure at this path `src/main/ml-config/rest-api.json` but I am not able to figure out how can I configure it to create multiple REST API instances.

One work around I know to create it via http PUT call to `mlHost:8002/v1/rest-apis`.But I want to do it via ml-gradle configuration.